# Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running './gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.6'

Tags: apache-kafka

I've searched a lot for solving this issue but nothing worked for me.

I'm trying to install Kafka on my linux machine (Mint) and I've reached to this step where I start the Kafka broker:

```sh
$ sudo /usr/local/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon /usr/local/kafka/config/server.properties
```

but I get the famous annoying error:

```sh
Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running './gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.6'
```

Any help please?

P.S. I've downloaded the Kafka binary (not the source)

Answer (score 1):

According to the output, you have not downloaded the binary package, as it is asking you to compile/package the code.

Or you have moved the `kafka-run-class.sh` binary somewhere where it cannot  reference the necessary CLASSPATH for running the server

You don't need `sudo` to run Kafka ... Try downloading/starting outside of `/usr/local` first - https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Comment: I'm sure I've downloaded the binary, not the source (`kafka_2.13-3.1.0.tgz`) and I've seen that `kafka-run-class.sh` file exists on this path `$HOME/kafka/bin` after I moved kafka directory from `/usr/local` to $HOME. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?
I get this error when I run the first command in the tutorial you sent: `Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.Kafka
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.Kafka`

Comment: I've raised the previous comment as a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361123 Thanks!