# Could not find or load main class kafka.Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to install Kafka on my linux machine (Mint) following this tutorial: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Here is what I did:

1. I've [downloaded the binary (kafka_2.13-3.1.0.tgz)](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/3.1.0/kafka_2.13-3.1.0.tgz), not the source
2. I moved Kafka directory to $HOME.
3. Ran the first line, on the quick tutorial link, but failed

This:
`$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

but received this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.Kafka
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.Kafka
```

So what could be reason to that error?

Comment: There is quite an [important note](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart) `Your local environment must have Java 8+ installed.`. Did you install Java 8+ on your machine?

Comment: Yes, `openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode)`

Comment: That's weird. Can you share the direct URL of the Kafka binary that you downloaded?

Comment: Sure. Here: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/3.1.0/kafka_2.13-3.1.0.tgz with Scala 2.13 version

Comment: Can you please edit kafka-server-start.sh and add line with `set -xv` after the shebang line? Then run again and show its output? Otherwise, I'd recommend just using Docker

Comment: @OneCricketeer Still the same error: `Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running './gradlew jar -PscalaVersion=2.13.6'` after adding `set -xv` after the shebang. Thanks, I think I should use docker yes. Is it advisable to do it through docker compose? not just a docker image for kafka and zookeeper?

Comment: It should actually print out debug bash information before that error, though, but yes, Compose is preferred; I use the images here, usually https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka